Selecting coefficient rows for statsmodels.iolib.summary.Summary
I am building a real estate model and one-hot encoded the first three digits of zip code. I don't want to see all those zip codes. How can I print(model.summary()) for all the other features?

print(model.summary().tables[0])
results_df = pd.DataFrame(model.summary().tables[1])
display(results_df[0:14])

